# What randomness algorithm does Array#sample use?

Tags: ruby, cryptography

I'm trying to figure out which random algorithm `Array#sample` uses, but I'm getting a bit lost hunting around in the Ruby C code.

Comment: So here is a rabbit hole to run down [sample](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_5/array.c#L4759) and all the other calls are available in [random.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_5/random.c). So it appears [Random](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Random.html) class might be what you are actually asking about which states "PRNGs are currently implemented as a modified Mersenne Twister with a period of 2**19937-1."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it helpful to dig in pry to examine actual source code although you can find it also by going to [Ruby Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#sample) and hover the method names to reveal the `click to toggle source` with magnifying glass which will also show you the same source code you can find here in pry, if you've done `gem install pry-doc`

```c
arr = []
cd arr
show-method sample

(#<Array>):1> show-method sample

From: array.c (C Method):
Owner: Array
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 103

static VALUE
rb_ary_sample(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE ary)
{
    VALUE nv, result;
    VALUE opts, randgen = rb_cRandom;
    long n, len, i, j, k, idx[10];
    long rnds[numberof(idx)];

    if (OPTHASH_GIVEN_P(opts)) {
        VALUE rnd;
        ID keyword_ids[1];

        keyword_ids[0] = id_random;
        rb_get_kwargs(opts, keyword_ids, 0, 1, &rnd);
        if (rnd != Qundef) {
            randgen = rnd;
        }
    }
    len = RARRAY_LEN(ary);
    if (argc == 0) {
        if (len < 2)
            i = 0;
        else
            i = RAND_UPTO(len);

        return rb_ary_elt(ary, i);
    }
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "1", &nv);
    n = NUM2LONG(nv);
    if (n < 0) rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "negative sample number");
    if (n > len) n = len;
    if (n <= numberof(idx)) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            rnds[i] = RAND_UPTO(len - i);
        }
    }
    k = len;
    len = RARRAY_LEN(ary);
    if (len < k && n <= numberof(idx)) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (rnds[i] >= len) return rb_ary_new_capa(0);
        }
    }
    if (n > len) n = len;
    switch (n) {
      case 0:
        return rb_ary_new_capa(0);
      case 1:
        i = rnds[0];
        return rb_ary_new_from_values(1, &RARRAY_AREF(ary, i));
      case 2:
        i = rnds[0];
        j = rnds[1];
        if (j >= i) j++;
        return rb_ary_new_from_args(2, RARRAY_AREF(ary, i), RARRAY_AREF(ary, j));
      case 3:
        i = rnds[0];
        j = rnds[1];
        k = rnds[2];
        {
            long l = j, g = i;
            if (j >= i) l = i, g = ++j;
            if (k >= l && (++k >= g)) ++k;
        }
        return rb_ary_new_from_args(3, RARRAY_AREF(ary, i), RARRAY_AREF(ary, j), RARRAY_AREF(ary, k));
    }
    if (n <= numberof(idx)) {
        long sorted[numberof(idx)];
        sorted[0] = idx[0] = rnds[0];
        for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
            k = rnds[i];
            for (j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                if (k < sorted[j]) break;
                ++k;
            }
            memmove(&sorted[j+1], &sorted[j], sizeof(sorted[0])*(i-j));
            sorted[j] = idx[i] = k;
        }
        result = rb_ary_new_capa(n);
        RARRAY_PTR_USE(result, ptr_result, {
            for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
                ptr_result[i] = RARRAY_AREF(ary, idx[i]);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        result = rb_ary_dup(ary);
        RBASIC_CLEAR_CLASS(result);
        RB_GC_GUARD(ary);
        RARRAY_PTR_USE(result, ptr_result, {
            for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
                j = RAND_UPTO(len-i) + i;
                nv = ptr_result[j];
                ptr_result[j] = ptr_result[i];
                ptr_result[i] = nv;
            }
        });
        RBASIC_SET_CLASS_RAW(result, rb_cArray);
    }
    ARY_SET_LEN(result, n);

    return result;
}
```

So we can see

```c
    VALUE opts, randgen = rb_cRandom;
```

This would indicate the ruby Random class c is used for the randomness.

The code alone wouldn't tell us much about the algo

So lookup of https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Random.html tells us it uses

> PRNGs are currently implemented as a modified Mersenne Twister with a period of 2**19937-1.

And what the heck is a `Mersenne Twister`?  I don't know but it sounds cool  so https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister tells us about it and that it is exstensively used:

> The Mersenne Twister is the default PRNG for the following software systems: Microsoft Excel,[3] GAUSS,[4] GLib,[5] GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library,[6] GNU Octave,[7] GNU Scientific Library,[8] gretl,[9] IDL,[10] Julia,[11] CMU Common Lisp,[12] Embeddable Common Lisp,[13] Steel Bank Common Lisp,[14] Maple,[15] MATLAB,[16] Free Pascal,[17] PHP,[18] Python,[19][20] R,[21] Ruby,[22] SageMath,[23] Scilab,[24] Stata.[25]

Comment: Sidenote: Your code snippet is from ruby < 2.5 (2.5 [`Array#sample`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_5/array.c#L4862)) but your reference to `Random` is 2.5.0 (which is different than `Random` < 2.5)

Comment: just because `Kernel#rand` is the same does not mean `Random` class is the same [2.4 random_raw_seed `Random::raw_seed`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_5/random.c#L633) vs [2.5 random_raw_seed `Random::urandom`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_5/random.c#L633) which bleeds into `fill_random_bytes_urandom` so since the way the random seed is generated changed I would still say yes it has changed albeit minor modifications that are not impactful to the answer. [Commits](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commits/ruby_2_5/random.c)

Comment: @engineersmnky - thanks for pointing this stuff out! looks like you accidentally linked to the 2.5 source in your 2.4 link above.

Comment: @JohnBachir you are correct sorry [Correct Link](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_4/random.c#L613)